# Load resources? - wxPython / Python

Tags: python, resources, wxpython

I am using wxPython and Py2exe to create my application and my only problem is loading for example bitmaps.

Ok so lets say I want to add an image to my application, and thats fairly easy using wxPython, and lets say it is on the same directory of my .py so for example:

```
image = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('image.bmp')
```

Now, this works obviously fine, problem is when I convert to Py2exe, I would like to use the resources from the dlls that I included in the Py2Exe compilation.

So basically what I want to do is to instead of including the images on the same folder as my application in order to work, I would like to use it from the resources so people won't see the images on the folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [img2py](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.tools.img2py-module.html). This tool is designed to convert images into python files you can import and package using py2exe.

Comment: though this won't really 'hide' his images, like he seems to want to do

Comment: +1 Also, for a more complete discussion, see http://groups.google.com/group/PyInstaller/browse_thread/thread/e999838588e7fd99